# Faster jQuery code for duplicate list item removal

Tags: jquery, html

I have following jQuery code for removing duplicate list items. Is there a better/faster approach? http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Hb28u/16/

**HTML**

```
   <div style="width: 100px">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-color: Red">A</li>
            <li style="background-color: Red">B</li>
            <li style="background-color: Orange">B</li>
            <li style="background-color: Red">C</li>
            <li style="background-color: Orange">C</li>
            <li style="background-color: Yellow">C</li>
            <li style="background-color: Red">D</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" class="submitButton" />
```

**jQuery**

```
        $('.submitButton').click(function (e) {
            alert('Begin');
            var previousVal = 'Initial';

            $('ul li').each(function (i, item) {
                var currentVal = $(item).text();
                if (currentVal == previousVal) {
                    $(item).remove();
                }
                previousVal = currentVal;
            });

            alert('End');
            return false;
        }
        );
```

Comment: @Andorbal Looking for better code since I will have many list items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this, but havent tested if its faster or not, both seem fast for me.

```
 var seen = {};
$('ul li').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
    return false;
}
);
```

Here is a fiddle with my solution that tell you the time it takes to execute. http://jsfiddle.net/54cdR/

Comment: This solution handles non-contiguous duplicates, which the original version does not.

Comment: @Andorbal That's true :-) - I already noticed that my original code will work only if the duplicates are in adjacent positions

Comment: Also, $.each() is much slower compared to a simple for loop is JavaScript. To improve performance, I would recommend using a for loop. http://jsperf.com/asdasda223/4